# Select... for update & commit, in nested fashion

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, mysql-connector

I am using MySQL Connector/C++ and here is my pseudo-code. I have two functions and a common function being called by those two functions:

```
CommonFunction()
{
   selects some rows for update
  // ... Do some transactions here ...
   commit transaction 
}

Function1()
{
  CommonFunction();
  // ... Do some activities here ...
}

Function2()
{
  selects some rows for update
  // ... Do some transactions here ...
  CommonFunction();
  // ... Do some other transactions here ...
  commit transaction 
}
```

**Problem:**

If I call `Function1` it calls `CommonFunction` which locks rows for update then does some transactions then commits. Works fine.

But when I call `Function2` it does some transactions and calls `CommonFunction` which after doing its job calls commit. But this commit also causes to release rows selected for update in `Function2` before it does 'some other transactions'.

Please can someone tell how to solve this? Please note, for demo purpose I've  explained it using minimum functions. Actual code is more complex and I don't want to disturb modularity (for e.g. by removing `commit` in `CommonFunction` it will impact whole lot of code). Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited**

To get something akin to nested transactions, use `SAVEPOINT name` and `RELEASE SAVEPOINT name`.  For "rollback": `ROLLBACK WORK TO SAVEPOINT name`.

Reference:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/savepoint.html